# Using powershell to access values

Tags: powershell, azure

I want to access value of "PrivateIpAddress" parameter which is inside "IpConfigurations". How can I do that? When I selected "IpConfigurations" ( command1 below), IPConfigurations->Name parameters value is shown by default (command 2-> IpConfigurations->Name). But I want to access IpConfigurations->PrivateIPAddress value.

Command1:

```
PS C:> Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup | Select Name, ResourceGroupName, IpConfigurations

Name                      ResourceGroupName  IpConfigurations
----                      -----------------  ----------------
zzz01.zzz.com-nic01       test-rg            {zzz01.zzz.com-nic01-ipconfig}
```

Command2:

```
PS C:> Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup


Name                        : zzz01.zzz.com-nic01
ResourceGroupName           : test-rg
Location                    : xxxx
Id                          : /xxxx
Etag                        : xxxxxx
ResourceGuid                : xxxx
ProvisioningState           : Succeeded
Tags                        :
VirtualMachine              : {
                                "Id": "/subscriptions/xxxx
                              }
IpConfigurations            : [
                                {
                                  "Name": "zzz01.zzz.com-nic01-ipconfig",
                                  "Etag": "W/\"xxxx",
                                  "Id": "xxxxxxx",
                                  "PrivateIpAddress": "10.65.179.179",
                  ......
                                }
                              ]
DnsSettings                 : {
                                "DnsServers": [],
                                "AppliedDnsServers": [],
                                "InternalDomainNameSuffix": "xxxx.net"
                              }
EnableIPForwarding          : False
EnableAcceleratedNetworking : False
NetworkSecurityGroup        : null
Primary                     : True
MacAddress                  : xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to Azure and so your command but maybe a command similar below would work:

```
(Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup|Get-NetIPConfiguration).PrivateIpAddress
```